# iPad and iPhone no longer connects to iMac since downloading IOS 9.0.2

Tags: itunes

Since downloading IOS 9.0.2 my iPhone and iPad no longer connect to iTunes in my iMac (OS X version 10.6.8). I get a message saying I need to update my ITunes, however I currently have version 11.4.8 and when I search for an update, it says there is no update. Please can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Current iTunes is 12.3 which will be required for iOS 9 devices to connect.

Your Catch 22 is that the minimum OS for iTunes 12 is 10.8.5.

It would appear that your only alternative would be to update your OS.
However, unless you have previously purchased any of the OSes between 10.7 (Lion) & 10.10 (Yosemite) your only available option from the App Store will be 10.11 (El Capitan)

I couldn't even speculate on the compatibility issues you might have jumping 5 major releases in one go, but I wouldn't even dream of it without a full backup or clone in place first.